# Как изменять динамично высоту блока js

Tags: javascript, css

Вот есть у меня блок `А` который имеет `position:absolute`. Он вложенный в нормальный блок `В` с `position:relative`. Проблема в том что когда блок `А` вылазит из-за пределов блока `В` - он и вылазит за пределы `body`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="B">
  <div class="A">
     <ul>
        <li>test</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.A {
   position:absolute;
   top:20px;
   left:3px; 
}
.B {
   position:relative;
   height:200px;
   width:300px;
}
```

Как добиться такого эффекта как на фейсбук который меняет высоту блока друзей когда он пытается вылезти за граници боди. По сути у них резиновый блок который меняет свою высоту что-бы не вылезти за граници

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```js
var outer = document.getElementsByClassName('B'),
    inner = document.getElementsByClassName('A');

outer[0].style.height = inner[0].offsetHeight + 15 + 'px';
```

```css
.A {
  background: gold;
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:5px; 
  width: 300px;
}


.B {
  background: pink;
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  width:300px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="B">
  <div class="A">
     <ul>
        <li>test</li>
       <li>test</li>
       <li>test</li>
       <li>test</li>
       <li>test</li>
       <li>test</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: хорошее решение ! 5 вам

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(function() {
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var hA = $(".A").height();
      $(".B").css('height', hA);
    });
});
```

```css
.A {
   position:absolute;
   top:20px;
   left:3px; 
  
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.B {
   position:relative;
   height:200px;
   width:300px;
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="B">
  <div class="A">
     <ul>
        <li>test</li>
       <li>test</li>
       <li>test</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```